# Focus current craft on orbit map

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I lost focus of my craft on the orbit map and I'm flying far away from any celestial bodies that I can focus. I have to plan a maneuver but a single pixel on my current flight path represents a couple of hours of flight time since I cannot get a good angle on in. Is there any way to regain focus on my craft like i can click on Kerbal or Minmus for instance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the backtick `` ` `` key to focus on your current ship. This should reset the zoom level as well as the position.

Comment: Does this still work? I tried it but backspace did nothing

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, as reported by David.

Comment: it is now `~` (the tilde key)

Answer (score 24):

As of May the 4th (the time of my checking and verifying), the key used to focus the active vessel is the back quote:   `   .

(That is the key next to the 1 on the US keyboard layout)

Source: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/KerbalAcademy/comments/5k5ne5/how_to_focus_the_map_on_the_active_vessel_in_121/

Answer (score 5):

They changed it to <kbd>`</kbd> (also the <kbd>~</kbd> key).  It's the button to the left one the <kbd>1</kbd> key on the number line.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know of is to go through the tracking station if the ship isn't actually the active ship.  If it is the active ship, the way I typically return (which may not be the best way) is to increase time warp to the first level, focus on the sun, and then use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to get back to the ship.  A couple of notes on this: first is that if you have maneuver nodes, they'll be focused first, keep hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, and second, the time warp is so that you don't throttle your engine up.

Answer (score 0):

Double-left-clicking on your ship will change the focus to it, without changing anything else.

Comment: Somehow this does not work. I can switch focus to other objects that can be focused by double clicking.

Comment: @MennoGouw Hmm... weird. It works for me.